# How to run a script from another document

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

I have two doc LibreOffice calc test1.ods and test2.ods.
I want run a script in test2 from the script of test1.

1. When test2 is open by the script of test1, i can't run the script on test2 even from test2. How i can pass out the security for the test2 doc ?
2. How i can run automaticly the scrip on test2 from the script on test1 ?

```html
REM  *****  BASIC  *****
'Script on Test1
Sub Main

Dim urlDest As String
Dim PropFich(1) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
Dim oDocDest As Object

    PropFich(0).Name = "MacroExecutionMode" 
    PropFich(0).value = com.sun.star.document.MacroExecMode.ALWAYS_EXECUTE
    urlDest = ConvertToUrl("/home/patrick/Bureau/Test/test2.ods")
    oDocDest = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromUrl(urlDest, "_blank", 0, PropFich())
    ' ...
    'run oDocDest.Standard.Module1.Main() ???
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the script provider of the other document and use it to invoke the macro.

```vb
oScriptProvider = oDocDest.getScriptProvider()
oScript = oScriptProvider.getScript(_
    "vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Module1.Main?language=Basic&location=document")
result = oScript.invoke(Array(), Array(), Array())
```

For this to work, you need to allow macros to run by going to *Tools > Options > Security*.

Comment: Thanks, I’m testing this tonight, but what’s the point of the Array(). Is there argument ? : invoke(Array(), Array(), Array()

Comment: Your `Main()` routine does not require any arguments, so that is why the array is empty.

Comment: Ok, if I had any arguments they MUST be in arrays?

Comment: It works perfectly. With MacroExecMode.ALWAYS_EXECUTE the test2 script runs without changing the Options Security section